# Is it possible to express an if statement in algebra?

Tags: logic

In programming languages it is possible to write functions that use if statements that can be plotted on Cartesian coordinates. For example:

```
function myfunc(x) 
{
   if (x > 0) 
      return 5;
   else 
      return 3;
}
```

Is is possible to represent something like this algebraically?

More generally, is it possible to express if statements algebraically?

Comment: i this using logic will only be possible to return FALSE or true, not numbers.

Comment: What does algebraically mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Check out Indicator functions. They will help you represent if statements in mathematical form.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is where I need to begin reading.

Comment: Basically, an indicator function is created by converting a boolean value (true, false) to a number (1, 0).  Some have proposed a special notation like $\;\#(x > 0)\;$, which is 1 if $\;x\;$ is 42, and 0 if $\;x\;$ is -1.  Instead of indicator functions, others have proposed a more general notation $\;5 \text{ if } x > 0 \text{ else } 3\;$.  With proper manipulation rules, these qualify as algebraic rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider absolute value an algebraic tool, then since it is essentially an *if/then* statement, you can use it to do this kind of thing. Your example would be $$f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}+4$$ which *almost* works except this is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: Clever, thanks! Not sure if it works in general though?

Comment: Since $\frac{|x|}{x}$ is basically a switch, you can use this to make all kinds of piecewise functions. $\frac{\frac{|x-h|}{x-h}+1}{2}$ can be used as a coefficient to "turn on" a function for $x>h$ and "turn it off" for $x<h$. But it doesn't exist at $x=h$. Also, if you only want to turn on a function in $(a,b)$, there's $\frac{\frac{|x-a|}{x-a} - \frac{|x-b|}{x-b}}{2}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan do you know a way to fix the divide by zero problem here?  This is a great trick and I would like to use it but I can't unless can fix the divide by zero.

Comment: I don't know of any elementary functions that are defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$, continuous on $(-\infty,a]$ for some $a$ and also on $(a,\infty)$, but discontinuous at $a$. And that is what is desired here.

Answer (score 1):

Try, for example

$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R,$$

with

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 5&&\text{if}~ x>0 \\ 3&&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Did I correctly undestand what you mean with "algebraically"?

Comment: Sure! cases is a handy shortcut. I left your && in place where a & would do just fine, but && moves into another column and left more space - up to you if you want to change that.